# Laravel Themes Manager enable theme

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to enable theme from a view in [hexadog's Theme Manager](https://github.com/hexadog/laravel-themes-manager) package but It always print Disabled as theme status:

index.blade.php:

```
@foreach ($themes as $theme)
                    <div class="col-md-3 mt-5">
                        <div class="theme-card">
                            <h3 class="theme-name">{{ $theme->getName() }}</h3>
                            <p class="theme-description">{{ $theme->getDescription() }}</p>
                            <p class="theme-version">{{ $theme->getVersion() }}</p>
                            
                            @if ($theme->enabled())
                                <p class="theme-status">Enabled</p>
                            @else
                                <p class="theme-status">Disabled</p>
                            @endif

                            <form method="POST" action="{{ route('themes.activate', ['themeName' => $theme->getName()]) }}">
                                @csrf
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Activate</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
```

ThemeController.php:

```
public function index()
    {
        $themes = ThemesManager::all();
        return view('admin.themes.index', compact('themes'));
    }

    public function activate(Request $request, $themeName)
    {
        if (!ThemesManager::has($themeName)) {
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Theme not found');
        }
        ThemesManager::enable($themeName);

        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Theme enabled');
    }
```

route for the activate method:

```
Route::post('/themes/activate/{themeName}', [ThemeController::class, 'activate'])->name('themes.activate');
```

When I click on the Activate button its return back with the "Theme enabled" success message and the status is still disabled, why?

*- I tried to delete the theme folder and then click on Activate button and then returned back with the error Theme not found message, so it's working I think -*

Comment: It's ok to ask a question about a 3rd party package on Stackoverflow, as it's quite possible that someone has encountered the issue before, or it's a simple syntax issue/typo, etc., but I would also consider using the [Issues section of the GitHub page](https://github.com/hexadog/laravel-themes-manager/issues) if you don't get any help here. At a glance, I don't see an issue with your code; `public function enabled()` in the source code returns `$this->enabled`, which is `true` or `false` if the Theme is enabled or not, so you should see `Enabled` _somewhere_ in `index.blade.php`.